# Why nested iterator closures won't copy values from outer scope

Tags: closures, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to use nested iterators, where the inner iterator uses value from the outer iterator.

```
vec![0;10].iter().flat_map(|&a| {
    (0..10).map(|b|{
        a + b
    })
});
```

> error: `a` does not live long enough
>
> ```
>     (0..10).map(|b|{
>                 ^^^
> ```
>
> note: reference must be valid for the method call...

This compiles if I move the inner closure (`move |b|{`), but I don't understand why it is necessary, given that `a` is an integer and could have been copied instead of moved.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#closures-and-their-environment

In short closures borrows its environment by default. With `move` it take ownership of the environment. If value copyable it can not be moved and will be copied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `flat_map` and `map` are lazy. The inner `map` does not use `a` immediately but tries to “save” it for when it will be needed later thus borrows `a`. But since `a` is local to the outer closure and you return `map`'s result, that borrow would become invalid. You would need to consume the inner iterator:

```
vec![0;10].iter().flat_map(|&a| {
    (0..10).map(|b|{
        a + b
    }).collect::<Vec<_>>()
});
```

Of course that's not efficient, and it would be much better for the inner closure to "keep" `a`. You would do this by marking the inner closure as `move`:

```
vec![0;10].iter().flat_map(|&a| {
    (0..10).map(move |b|{
        a + b
    })
});
```

Normally, the compiler would not let you do this, because the `flat_map` closure does not own `a`, it merely has a reference to it. However,
since the numeric types in Rust (like `isize`) implement the `Copy` trait, the compiler will copy `a` instead of trying to move it, giving the behavior you want. Note that this is also the reason why you are allowed to dereference `a` (using `|&a|`) in the `flat_map`; normally that would have required owning `a`, not merely a reference to it (which is what `.iter()` yields).