# flat_map with a nested iterator in Rust

Tags: rust

I tried to write code similar to this:

```
fn main() {
    let i = ['a', 'b'];
    let qux = i.iter().flat_map(|&foo| {
        let bar = [foo, 'c'];
        (0usize..42).map(|ii| {
            bar.iter() /*.map(some_function)*/ .collect::<String>()
        })
    }).min();
}
```

This does not work because `bar` does not live long enough, and I have not found any solution for which the borrow checker does not complain. Is there any chance to do this sort of thing in a functional style?

Also, why does `flat_map` necessarily move or copy the values? I would imagine that, if I could do

```
    let qux = i.iter().map(|&foo| [foo, 'c']).flat_map(|&bar| {
        /* ... */
    }).min();
```

that it would be able to ensure that `bar` lives long enough.

Comment: I was about to answer your question, but admittedly, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38551294/1233251) feels like an acceptable duplicate. In short, the closure in the inner `map` does not own `bar`, so right now it would have a reference to something that only exists in `flat_map`'s closure (remember that iterators are lazy). To solve this, just collect the inner iterator or add the `move` keyword to the closure, so that `bar` becomes owned. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1b21fd1c703a6271ca3419814980a7e&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: @E_net4 Hmm, yes I think it is the same thing - not sure why I thought I couldn't reduce my example further. I did try collecting the inner iterator, but did not know a `Vec` is sufficient to return - I basically called `.collect().iter()` and that just deferred the problem.

Any wisdom on why `flat_map` has to consume the iterator's values at all?

Comment: `flat_map` expects a closure that returns an `IntoIterator` (which is something that consumes itself into an iterator). Any of your other concerns simply relate to the fact that the iterator alone might only have to borrow the necessary data for a full traversal. In this case however, it had to own the contents in `bar` so it can live as long as the iterator.